# Programmatically add Databricks spark-csv to Spark 1.6.2 client

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm working with Spark 1.6.2, developing a Python Spark client (it runs in `yarn-client` mode). The important thing here is, always in the client machine, **I cannot spark-submit my Python script, but I need to run the script as a Python script**.

At certain point of the code, I need to load a CSV file within HDFS as a Spark Dataframe (i.e. using a SQL context). As you may know, Spark 1.6.2 has no native support for CSV-based dataframes, and [Databricks spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) must be used.

The data loading sentence is as follows:

```
df = sql_context.read.load(format='com.databricks.spark.csv', path=url, header=True, inferSchema=False, delimiter=',')
```

**The problem is `com.databricks.spark.csv` is not found**.

I know the Databricks spark-csv jars must be downloaded and put somewhere. The question is: where? Is this a requirement in the client machine, or in the cluster?

Since I don't know, I've tried this at the client machine, without success:

- `export PYTHONPATH=/path/where/jars/were/downloaded/`.
- `conf = SparkConf().set('spark.jars', '/path/where/jars/were/downloaded/')`.
- `conf = SparkConf().set('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/path/where/jars/were/downloaded/')`. [[ref](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-add-jars-to-standalone-pyspark-program-td22685.html)]

I've also tried this at Spark cluster, without success too:

- Setting custom spark-defaults property `spark.jars` through Ambari.
- Setting custom spark-defaults property `spark.driver.extraClassPath`through Ambari.

I'll remember you that command line options as `--jars` or `--packages` are not suitable for me, since I'm not running any Spark script :)

Other solutions, such as doing setting the jar in the Spark context using `addJar()` will not work, since Spark 1.6.2 do not implement it.

So, any idea about how my code can find Databricks spark-csv jar?

Just in case, this is the error trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.csv. Please find packages at http://spark-packages.org
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$$anonfun$4.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:82)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ResolvedDataSource.scala:62)
        ... 14 more
```

Other post I've read...

- [Add jars to a Spark Job - spark-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit)
- [Spark submit does automatically upload the jar to cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391977/spark-submit-does-automatically-upload-the-jar-to-cluster)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found [this](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/247) issue at Databricks Github, and @drorata's answer worked for me:

```
export PACKAGES="com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0"
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--packages ${PACKAGES} pyspark-shell"
```

By exporting the above environment variables, Databrick spark-csv package (and dependencies) where downloaded to my local `.ivy2` folder, and automatically uploaded to the cluster while creating the Spark Context.